# How to implement K-means (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, k-means

I have a dataset, consisting of 61 rows and 28 columns (Category of Used Application). I am very much new with coding,I will try Machine learning algorithm for the first time, so I appreciate any help! .

This is what I have in terms of my data:

```
Category  Calendar  Clock  Communication  Education  Entertainment  Finance   
UserId                                                                         
  1                1      1              1          9              1         0   
  2                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  3                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  4                1      1              6          0              0         0   
  5                0      1              1          1              1         0   
  6                0      0              0          0              0         0   
  7                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  8                0      1              1          0              0         0   
  9                0      0              1          0              7         0   
  10               0      1              1          0              0         0   
  11               0      2              1          0              5         0   
  13               0      0              1          0              0         0   
  14               0      1              1          0              1         0   
  15               1      1              1          0              0         0   
  16               0      1              1          0              0         0   
  17               0      0              1          1              1         0   
  19               0      1              1          0              0         0   
  20               0      0              1          0              0         0   
  21               0      1              1          0              1         0   
  .....  
  61               0      1              1          0              5         0
```

I am looking for an implementation of k-means to cluster users in 3 groups with their behavior of used category .
How should i do!

Comment: Have you studied anything so far about k-means clustering?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: scikit-learn is a Machine Learning tool for python.  https://scikit-learn.org/

Comment: Yes I have some idea about how it works, but I couldn't implement with my data.
Also, the k-means may give interpretable results using my data ?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
from pylab import plot,show
from numpy import vstack,array
from numpy.random import rand
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(df['Feature1']),np.asarray(df['Feature2']),[np.asarray(df['Feature3'])]).T
X = data
distorsions = []
for k in range(2, 20):
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    k_means.fit(X)
    distorsions.append(k_means.inertia_)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(range(2, 20), distorsions)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Elbow curve')

centroids,_ = kmeans(data,3)
# assign each sample to a cluster
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)
# some plotting using numpy's logical indexing
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
     data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'oy',
     data[idx==2,0],data[idx==2,1])
plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'sg',markersize=8)
show()

details = [(name,cluster) for name, cluster in zip(df.index,idx)]
for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```

Comment: Thank you for your ressponnse ! But it does not work!

Comment: It worked fine for me.  What doesn't work?  That's pretty vague.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Maps & Navigation'

Comment: I don't even see 'Maps & Navigation'.  Can you post your dataframe?  It would take me an hour to convert your raw data into an actual dataframe.  I don't have a full hour to devote to that.

Comment: Thank you! I apologize you for the time you've wasted.